# How to make page slide(change) with react-router

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I'v tried to use react-router and ReactTransitionGroup to make an navigation effect(page slide whereas route changes).

However, it's error-prone and ugly.(made much logic to define which direction to slide to and remove/add classes to make transition work).

I doubt is there any nice plugin to use.

Here's piece of my code, which inspired by [Hardware-Accelerated Page Transitions for Mobile Web Apps / PhoneGap Apps](http://coenraets.org/blog/2013/03/hardware-accelerated-page-transitions-for-mobile-web-apps-phonegap-apps/).

```
const keyHistory = [];

let dir = 0;

const PageMixin = {
    componentWillAppear(cb) {
        keyHistory.push(this.props.location.key);

        let $el = $(ReactDom.findDOMNode(this));

        $el.addClass(pageStyles.right);

        $el.one('transitionend', () => {
            $el.removeClass(`${pageStyles.right} ${pageStyles.active}`);
            cb();
        });

        requestAnimationFrame(() => {
            $el.addClass(`${pageStyles.active} ${pageStyles.center}`);
        });
    },

    componentWillEnter(cb) {
        let key = this.props.location.key,
            len = keyHistory.length; 
        if (key === keyHistory[len - 2]) {
            keyHistory.pop();
            dir = -1;
        } else {
            keyHistory.push(key);
            dir = 1;
        }

        const fromDir = dir === -1 ? pageStyles.left : pageStyles.right;

        let $el = $(ReactDom.findDOMNode(this));

        $el.addClass(fromDir);

        requestAnimationFrame(() => {
            $el.removeClass(fromDir).addClass(`${pageStyles.active} ${pageStyles.center}`);
        });

        $el.one('transitionend', () => {
            $el.removeClass(`${fromDir} ${pageStyles.active}`);
            cb();
        });


    },

    componentWillLeave(cb) {

        const toDir = dir === -1 ? pageStyles.right : pageStyles.left;

        let $el = $(ReactDom.findDOMNode(this));

        requestAnimationFrame(() => {
            $el.removeClass(pageStyles.center).addClass(`${pageStyles.active} ${toDir}`);
        });

        $el.one('transitionend', () => {
            $el.removeClass(pageStyles.active);
            cb();
        });
    }
};
```

Comment: I made it as a plugin by myself [react-router-pageslider](https://github.com/dyf19118/react-router-pageslider)

Answer (score 2):

You can try this

https://github.com/oliviertassinari/react-swipeable-views

Partial code from github

```
  <SwipeableViews>
    <div>
      slide 1
    </div>
    <div>
      slide 2
    </div>
    <div>
      slide 3
    </div>
  </SwipeableViews>
```

Answer (score 2):

You could be interested having a look at https://github.com/doctolib/react-router-transitions.
This plugin handles the logic part of the transition.

You would still have to handle the actual transition on your side. E.g. by using `ReactTransitionGroup`.

Answer (score 2):

Coming in abit late but, without any other packages, There's a nice example in the examples of react-router right [Here](https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/tree/master/examples/animations)

Using ReactCSSTransitionGroup would look like this:

```
<ReactCSSTransitionGroup
     component="div"
     transitionName={ location.action !== 'POP' ? 'slide': 'slide-back' }
     transitionEnterTimeout={1000}
     transitionLeaveTimeout={1000}>
      {React.cloneElement(children, { key: location.pathname })}
</ReactCSSTransitionGroup>
```

for the slide you can use the method shown in [Sliding React Components](https://medium.com/front-end-developers/sliding-react-components-4873e232907e#.9400gf4s8):

```css
.slide-enter {
  transform: translate(100%);
}
.slide-enter.slide-enter-active {
  transform: translate(0%);
  transition: transform 1000ms ease-in-out;
}
.slide-leave {
  transform: translate(0%);
}
.slide-leave.slide-leave-active {
  transform: translate(-100%);
  transition: transform 1000ms ease-in-out;
}

.slide-back-enter{
  transform: translate(-100%);
}

.slide-back-enter.bg-back-enter-active {
  transform: translate(0%);
  transition: transform 1000ms ease-in-out;
}
.slide-back-leave {
  transform: translate(0%);
}
.slide-back-leave.bg-back-leave-active {
  transform: translate(0%);
  transition: transform 1000ms ease-in-out;
}
```

Comment: github link is broken! :( @Matan

Comment: @rehman_00001 you can try this one:
https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/blob/master/packages/react-router-dom/examples/Animation/index.js